# binary.Write() byte ordering not working for []byte

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
)

func main(){
    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    c := new(bytes.Buffer)
    binary.Write(b, binary.LittleEndian, []byte{0, 1})
    binary.Write(b, binary.BigEndian, []byte{0, 1})
    binary.Write(c, binary.LittleEndian, uint16(256))
    binary.Write(c, binary.BigEndian, uint16(256))
    fmt.Println(b.Bytes()) // [0 1 0 1]
    fmt.Println(c.Bytes()) // [0 1 1 0]
}
```

It is very interesting, why `binary.Write()` byte ordering is working for `uint8, uint16, uint64`..etc, but `[]byte`?

If `[]byte` need to be ordered by `binary.LittleEndian` and write to `bytes.Buffer`, it needs to be reversed first? Is there any effective ways to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Only integer types get swapped by byte ordering.

When it's a slice of bytes, the binary package wouldn't really know what to swap.

For example, how would it know what to do if you passed 1k of data?

Treat it as int16, int32 or int64?

Or would you expect it to just reverse the whole slice?

Answer (score 2):

Because there is nothing to order by. A byte is 8 bits, so you can go (unsigned) from 0 to 255. ie. `uint16` you have 2 bytes, so you can order them differently.

[`ByteOrder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#ByteOrder) is not even defined for `int8`. You can check the [source code](https://golang.org/src/encoding/binary/binary.go?s=7232:7296#L240) to see that `binary.Write` simply not uses the passed order when types are `uint8` or `int8`. (A `byte` is an alias to `uint8`)